# Splash Screen Java Program

Tags: java, swing, splash-screen

When I start my .JAR file from the command line, I can specify a splash screen to show while my program is loading, like this:

```
java -splash:mySplash.png -jar myJAR.jar
```

This will show mySplash.png in the center of the screen when starting up.

I want to do something exactly like this, except I want it to be part of my JAR.
Also, I want it to use a PNG that is inside a JAR in the build path. 
How can I go about creating a method that will let you do:

```
Class.showSplash(resource.path.to.png.png, intTimeInSeconds);
```

I want it to be able to show a PNG splash for the amount of time given.

I don't really know how to show the PNG, position it, or select the PNG to show.

Comment: Do you still want to use the splash screen API?

Comment: I really don't care how it would work it just needs to be part of the JAR. (No batch scripts to open it, etc.)

Comment: Have you look at the section "How to Use a JAR File to Display Splash Screen" from the [How to Create a Splash Screen](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/splashscreen.html)?

Comment: Yes but I find it somewhat confusing (I am beginner in Java), and need to know how I would make it work as described above.

Comment: Oracle tutorial is rather easy. I followed them replacing GIF by PNG and it just works. So if you are confused with tutorial, you must explain exactly what is not clear